# Add dependency to an ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, nuget

I'm trying to use the forecast API with my ASP.NET CORE app. I'm a linux user so I downloaded the nugget CLI and run it with Mono.I downloaded the c# wrapper from here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Forecast.io/. Then under project.json i added the dependency

**project.json**

`"Forecast.io":"1.0.10"`

However i get `error NU1002: The dependency Forecast.io 1.0.10 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.`

How do have to link the package in my project so I can use the dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you target Mono, you don't have to use .NET Core (`netcoreapp1.0` is the .NET Core application target moniker).

ASP.NET Core doesn't mean it only runs on .NET Core. ASP.NET also runs against the Full .NET Framework (4.5.1 or higher or mono).

All you need to do is remove the `netcoreapp1.0` moniker and replace it with `net451`. Also don't forget to remove the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` package, if it's still there.

Your frameworks section in project.json should look something like this:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net452": { }
  },
```